# Openshift port issues while installing ldap Opendj

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

hi i have unzipped opendj in data directory , now i am trying to install opendj but none of the ports are allowing me to bind even in the range above `15000` i am using the `OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP=127.3.231.1` insternal ip still facing issue

### example

What would you like to use as the initial root user DN for the Directory
Server? `[cn=Directory Manager]`:

Please provide the password to use for the initial root user:

Please re-enter the password for confirmation:

Provide the fully-qualified directory server host name that will be used when
generating self-signed certificates for **LDAP SSL/StartTLS**, the administration
connector, and replication

```
[ex-std-node351.prod.rhcloud.com]: openam-avsrecon.rh 
cloud.com
```

**i used the internal ip also here**
On which port would you like the Directory Server to accept connections from
**LDAP clients**? `[389]: 15389`

> ERROR: Unable to bind to port 15389. This port may already be in use,
>   or you may not have permission to bind to it

On which port would you like the Directory Server to accept connections from
LDAP clients? `[389]: 0000`

> Invalid port number "0000". Please enter a valid port number between 1
>   and 65535

On which port would you like the Directory Server to accept connections from
**LDAP clients**? `[389]`:

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are actually binding to the correct ip address, if you are referring to this line

```
Provide the fully-qualified directory server host name that will be used when generating self-signed certificates for LDAP SSL/StartTLS, the administration connector, and replication
```

This is only for the self signed ssl certificate generation.  It looks like you are not binding to the correct ip address, and most likely your application is binding to 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces).  You may need to further consult the documentation about where to specify the ip to bind to.